# how to keep tab bar while go to another view controller. Swift

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

What should I do if I want to use the tab bar in VC4 VC5 and VC6? Any function I should call? Or, I can just click something in inspector?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and the solution I discovered was this: rather than connecting the tab bar controller directly to VC1, VC2, and VC3, instead connect it to three new navigation controllers, the root view controllers of which are VC1, VC2, and VC3 respectively. This should do what you're looking for, hope it helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

Your question and storyboard structure is unclear as the photo is very small and it's not easily apparent what you're trying to accomplish.

That said, I think what you mean to do is have VC1, VC2, and VC3 each have a navigation controller embedded, then push VCs 4, 5, and 6 from 1, 2, and 3 respectively. That will preserve the tab bar while you're pushing through a separate navigation stack.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  It can't be.  You even state that you have no clue what the user is trying to accomplish.

Comment: That's a very strange stance. It in fact is an answer. An answer to a common problem, which I believe speaks to the question even though it is, as posed, somewhat unclear.